# Render different tabs on BottomTabNavigator based on params

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an app that starts with a loader screen where I determine whether the user is an admin or not. This screen navigates to a BottomTabNavigator, but I want to show different tabs based on whether the user is admin or not. I looked at the documentation for [custom navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html) but this still requires the navigator to be created outside the class, so I can't use the params. I also tried this:

```
export default class BottomTabNavigator extends Component {
  render() {
    const BottomTabComponent = createBottomTabNavigator({
      ...
    });
    return (
      <BottomTabComponent {...this.props} />
    );
  }
}
```

But that doesn't work either (seems like I shouldn't pass the navigation prop down). Removing `{...this.props}` is also no good because then I would have to wrap the component in an app container, but that is also not right, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: just to clarify, do you want to have two navigation bars (shown depending on the screen) or do you want different icons to the defaults in the BottomTabNavigator plugin? (or both..)

Comment: I want to be able to hide some of the icons in the bottom tab bar. Right now, when my loader navigates into the the bottom tab navigator, I'm passing a parameter that specifies that some tabs should be hidden, but I'm not sure if that's the right approach either.

Comment: An aside to your question.. I tried to customise the BottomTabNavigator [about a year ago - I wanted different height/ bigger icons etc] and it proved easier to examine the source code and then create my own tab navigator from scratch. It might be worth considering. Although it seems you're a good way there... promising..